# Does Analytics Script Conflict with Fade-in Effect?

Tags: javascript, jquery, google-analytics

I recently installed my analytics code, but it has been saying for a while that it's not installed.

I can't think of a better place to put it. Does the script interfere with my other script (for the fade-in)?

Also, should my script be the first thing I include? (maybe after `</title>`?)

Hits are showing under "real-time" but not as actual visits. The tracking info still says "tracking not installed." I refreshed to make sure.

**UPDATE:** Google is showing my hits, and I have data... but it says that tracking is not installed. I've had this issue with Wordpress sites, but they were remedied with the use of a plug-in.

Should I try using the old tracking script? I know that one works.

```
<!doctype html>
<html>
<head>
<meta charset="UTF-8">
<title>Casey</title>
<meta name="description" content="" />
<meta name="keywords" content="">
<link href="home.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css">
<script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.9.1/jquery.min.js" ></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready(function() {
    if (window.localStorage && !localStorage['faded']) {
        localStorage['faded'] = true;
        $('body').hide().fadeIn(500);
    }
});
</script>
<script>
  (function(i,s,o,g,r,a,m){i['GoogleAnalyticsObject']=r;i[r]=i[r]||function(){
  (i[r].q=i[r].q||[]).push(arguments)},i[r].l=1*new Date();a=s.createElement(o),
  m=s.getElementsByTagName(o)[0];a.async=1;a.src=g;m.parentNode.insertBefore(a,m)
  })(window,document,'script','//www.google-analytics.com/analytics.js','ga');

  ga('create', 'UA-40498113-1', 'caseykidd.com');
  ga('send', 'pageview');

</script>
</head>
```

Comment: That's a pretty confusing script; I see what it's doing but I'm not sure I'd use something so convoluted, especially when _gaq accomplishes the same goals and is more widely used/recognized.

Comment: That's what Google rendered for me to use. Is there a better way that I should be using?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The only thing I see that's "off" is

`ga('create', 'UA-40498113-1', 'caseykidd.com');`

should be

`ga('create', 'UA-40498113-1', {'cookieDomain':'caseykidd.com'});`

But I don't think that's really the problem (I think GA is just ignoring how you did it and it happily works out okay, based on your lack of subdomain in the URL). **edit**: oddly, the generated code within the GA interface looks like what you have, but that's not what the documentation shows. I have verified that this is apparently an undocumented syntax shortcut for setting the cookie domain.

You said you see the data in the "real time" reports so I assume your account number is correct.

My only suggestion is to wait a while for the data to show up.  GA's "real time" stuff only shows some basic info.  Stuff like "visit" may not be immediately available because of the nature of the dimension/metric.  For example, GA (and most other tracking tools) usually don't count it as a visit until the visit is actually over. So if you went to your site to test it and then immediately went to GA to check...well the visit isn't actually over until 30 minutes after the last request to GA.

**update** (*additional info based on your comment below and update to your question*)

I don't necessarily think you need to use the old tracking script.. I don't know how it works within Google's system, but Google actually officially states that it can take up to 24 hours for everything to be completely recorded.

Also to be fair, Universal Analytics (analytics.js) is open beta phase at the moment.. it could be that they haven't gotten around to updating that verification logic, or there could be a bug in it, or it could be one of the things that take closer to 24 hours to be updated.

Again, since you are seeing data, I don't think you are doing it wrong, but for sh*ts and grins you can read the entry on [verifying your web tracking setup](https://support.google.com/analytics/answer/1008083?hl=en&ref_topic=1008079). Are you testing on some other domain than what the web property is setup for? I think GA may not report that implementation has been verified if it has not received a request from the domain specified in the property settings. Also the the manual says it must be on the "homepage" of your site. Are you testing on the homepage or using a custom page name?

As a test I setup analytics.js code in a new web property for a domain that did not previously have any GA tracking on it, when I posted this answer. I see my data but the tracking status remains as "not installed." It has not been 24 hours for me yet, but I personally don't really care, as long as the data is coming in. Even [Google's troubleshooting document entry for tracking verification](https://developers.google.com/analytics/resources/articles/gaTrackingTroubleshooting#verifyingSetup) just says to look at the request and verify data in the reports, so that's good enough for me.

But if it really bothers you that much, and you've waited at least 24 hours, I would suggest posting a possible bug report on the google support forums.

**update 2**: It's been about 18 hours, since I last checked, and the status msg has changed to "receiving data" on my test domain/web property.

Comment: Do you think I should try using the old tracking script? See my update above.

Comment: Yep! Google is relaxing this weekend.

Comment: I just noticed, the `cookieDomain` change you added yields a syntax error.

Comment: I also mentioned in a previous edit that your original way apparently works fine - it's apparently an undocumented feature. Not sure why you had to go and remove the solved status for a simple syntax error..

Answer (score 0):

When you create a Google Analytics account you're provided with the tracker script, which in my experience has always been the below:

```
<script type="text/javascript">

  var _gaq = _gaq || [];
  _gaq.push(['_setAccount', 'UA-XXXXXXXX-1']);
  _gaq.push(['_trackPageview']);

  (function() {
    var ga = document.createElement('script'); ga.type = 'text/javascript'; ga.async = true;
    ga.src = ('https:' == document.location.protocol ? 'https://ssl' : 'http://www') + '.google-analytics.com/ga.js';
    var s = document.getElementsByTagName('script')[0]; s.parentNode.insertBefore(ga, s);
  })();

</script>
```

That uses the _gaq object, where basically you fill an array of arrays with stuff you want Google Analytics to do later, and when it loads it looks for _gaq, reads the array and executes those commands. It then replaces _gaq with an object that immediately responds to calls to .push() by executing the commands described in the array.

So for example if you added this to the array:

_gaq.push(['_trackEvent', 'Ordering', 'Clicked', 'Order Now top-left']);

Then one of 2 things would happen:

If GA hadn't loaded yet, this array would be added to the _gaq array, waiting for GA to finish loading. When GA did load it would read this and fire the trackEvent command with the parameters you included.

If GA had already loaded, then this call to .push() would cause the trackEvent command to be executed immediately, with the parameters you included.

By the way I usually simplify the example script to:

```
<script>
var _gaq = [
['_setAccount', 'UA-XXXXXXXX-1'],
['_trackPageview']];

(function() {
    var ga = document.createElement('script'); ga.async = true;
    ga.src = ('https:' == document.location.protocol ? 'https://ssl' : 'http://www') + '.google-analytics.com/ga.js';
    var s = document.getElementsByTagName('script')[0]; s.parentNode.insertBefore(ga, s);
})();
</script>
```